# Why normal vector and acceleration aren't the same?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I know the derivative of position vector function $r(t)$ is velocity, and its unit vector is tangent vector, therefore, the derivative of tangent vector is the unit vector of acceleration and normal vector. **Why isn't that the case?**

Comment: Imagine a particle moving in a straight line.  Is acceleration normal to the line?

Comment: What causes the difference?  Based on the formula, I can't tell how that happens

Comment: The derivatives in the Frenet-Serret frame are with respect to arclength, not time. Also I think it may be undefined for a particle moving in a straight line  (just based on symmetry), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, acceleration is the variation of velocity in time, and thus the derivative of the velocity function.

Write $x(t)$ for the position, $v(t):=\dot x(t)$ for the velocity, and $a(t):=\dot v(t)$ for the acceleration. The direction vector is
$$d(t):=\frac{v(t)}{\|v(t)\|}\ .$$
If we differentiate it, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}d(t) =&\ \frac{\dot v(t)}{\|v(t)\|} -\frac{\langle\dot v(t),v(t)\rangle}{\|v(t)\|^3}v(t)\\
=&\ \frac{a(t)}{\|v(t)\|} -\frac{\langle a(t),v(t)\rangle}{\|v(t)\|^3}v(t)\ .
\end{align}
This is of course different from the normal vector in general.

Comment: Is this what is called the principal normal? and this not orthogonal to the tangent plane which the common normal is?

Answer (score 4):

If speed  $(\|r'(t)\|)$ is constant, then the acceleration must be normal to the direction of travel.

But if speed is variable then acceleration can be broken into a component parallel to the direction of travel and a component that is perpendicular to the direction of travel.

Comment: The formula shows the differences. But I'm still confused, why isn't the derivative of unit tangent vector parallel with acceleration vector.

Comment: If we choose a space curve in the xyz 3-dimensional coordinate space, for two different unit tangent vectors, the difference between them is only the direction. Is that right?

Comment: $N$ is the second derivative of $r$ with respect to arc length $= \frac {d^2r}{dS^2}, a$ is the second derivative of $r$ with respect to time.

When we unitize the tangent vector, then we are dividing by $\| r'(t)\|$ (speed).  It is the direction of the particle, moving at constant speed.   $a = \frac {d^2r}{dt^2}  = \frac {d^2S}{dt^2} T + (\frac {dS}{dt})^2 N$